# Is there an easy method to determine the amount of x solution to be added to y solution to form 1%, 5%, 10%, 20%, and 40% solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, arithmetic, arithmetic-progressions

I'm doing some calculations for a chemistry experiment and have decided that I need solutions of 1%, 5%, 10%, 20% and 40% consisting of x mL of ethanol and y mL of solution y. Are there any possible methods for finding a combination of x and y to give me nice, whole numbers or half numbers? As of now, I've only been doing trial and error and it's doing my head in...

eg. 180 mL solution y:

$$180 mL + 120 mL \text{ ethanol } = 40\text{%}$$
$$180 mL + 45 mL \text{ ethanol } = 20\text{%}$$
$$180 mL + 20 mL \text{ ethanol } = 10\text{%}$$
$$180 mL + 9.47 mL \text{ ethanol } = 5\text{%}$$
$\rightarrow \text{this is where it starts to get messy... is there any faster method to find a solution?}$

Comment: What is the concentration of ethanol that you're starting with? Also, have you seen $c_1V_1=c_2V_2$ before?

Comment: starting with 100% ethanol; yes i've tried C1V1=C2V2, idk if I'm using it correctly cause the values i'm getting are impossible. Also, I don't think C1V1=C2V2 works here cause there are 2 unknown variables (the amount of solution y I begin with and the amount of ethanol I add)

Comment: Is there any ethanol in solution $y$? I'm asking this, since $$\frac{120}{180+120}=0.4$$

Comment: Nope, no ethanol in solution y

Comment: I've posted an answer, please let me know if it is helpful or not

Answer (score 0):

Say you want the concentration to be $p\%$ ethanol, then $$\frac{x}{x+y}=p\%$$ You can solve for $x$ to get $$x=\frac{p\%}{1-p\%}y$$

**Example**

With $p=60$ and $y=180$, you have $$x=\frac{0.60}{1-0.60}\cdot 180=270$$

---

$$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline y & p & x=\frac{p\%}{1-p\%}y \\ \hline 180 & 99 & 17820 \\ \hline 180 & 90 & 1620 \\ \hline 180 & 80 & 720 \\ \hline 180 & 70 & 420 \\ \hline 180 & 60 & 270 \\ \hline 180 & 50 & 180 \\ \hline 180 & 40 & 120 \\ \hline 180 & 30 & 77.\overline{142857} \\ \hline 180 & 20 & 45 \\ \hline 180 & 10 & 20 \\ \hline \end{array}$$